# polyBLAMP anti-aliasing in C++

Tags: audio, digital, oscillator, anti-aliasing-filter

How should 4 point polyBLAMP work. It does not really seem to dampen aliasing.

I have an floating point digital audio oscillator that makes a +1.0f jump at the end of every period.

My question is, have I misunderstood how it should work?

I have been using these as reference:
http://www.dafx17.eca.ed.ac.uk/papers/DAFx17_paper_100.pdf
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307990687_Rounding_Corners_with_BLAMP

Here is how I thought it should be done: (the code gets run every sample)

```
float t = phase / period; //normalized position in period
float dt = deltaPhase / period; // normalized phasestep

float polyBLAMP = 0.0f;
if (t < dt) {
    float d = (t)/dt; // fractional delay
    polyBLAMP = (3.0f*powf(d,5.0f)-10.0f*powf(d,4.0f)+40.0f*powf(d,2.0f)-60.0f*d/2.0f+28.0f)/120.0f;
} else if (t < dt*2.0f) {
    float d = (t-dt)/dt;
    polyBLAMP = (-powf(d,5.0f)+5.0f*powf(d,4.0f)-10.0f*powf(d,3.0f)+10.0f*powf(d,2.0f)-5.0f*d+1.0f)/120.0f;
} else if (t > 1.0f - dt) {
    float d = (dt-1.0f+t)/dt;
    polyBLAMP = (-3.0f*powf(d,5.0f)+5.0f*powf(d,4.0f)+10.0f*powf(d,3.0f)+10.0f*powf(d,2.0f)+5.0f*d+1.0f)/120.0f;
} else if (t > 1.0f - dt*2.0f) {
    float d = (2.0f*dt-1.0f+t)/dt;
    polyBLAMP = powf(d,5.0f)/120.0f;
}
float output = osc(phase)+polyBLAMP;
```

Comment: I'd love to hear what that pentagram oscillator sounds like.  It has subharmonics in addition to harmonics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if your phasor oscillator has a *step* discontinuity (as opposed to a ramp one) at $\phi\bmod 1 = 0$, then you should use the four-point, fourth order poly*BLEP* residual, not the fifth-order polyBLAMP one.

Second, the easiest way to simplify the piecewise polynomials is to see that the residuals are the successive integrals of the piecewise approximation to the band-limited pulse, or in the terminology of [Esqueda, Välimäki & Bilbao](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307990687_Rounding_Corners_with_BLAMP) [EVB2016], the “third-order B-spline basis function.” This basis function is needlessly complicated as given; it can be expressed as the difference of two overlapping piecewise polynomials:

$$
\frac{1}{6}\,\begin{cases}
(2+d)^3 & \text{if}\ {-2} \le d < 0 \\
(2-d)^3 & \text{if}\ \phantom{-}0 \le d < 2 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} -\
\frac{1}{6}\,\begin{cases}
4(1+d)^3 & \text{if}\ {-1} \le d < 0 \\
4(1-d)^3 & \text{if}\ \phantom{-}0 \le d < 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

From this, the successive residuals are trivial integrals of polynomials.

Third, the residuals are centered on $d=0$, where $d$ is the offset from the discontinuity to the immediately previous sample point, and the function extends two samples on either side of $0$. In order to apply them to a function of a phasor, the positive portion of the piecewise definition must be shifted to the $\phi=0$ discontinuity while the negative portion must be shifted to the $\phi=1$ discontinuity. Let $0\le\phi<1$ be the phase and $d\phi = f_0/f_s$ the phase increment. The modified polyBLEP in single-sided form is:

$$
\frac{1}{12}\,\begin{cases}
\left(2-\frac{\phi}{d\phi}\right)^4 & \text{if}\ 0\le \phi < 2d\phi \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} -\
\frac{1}{12}\,\begin{cases}
4\left(1-\frac{\phi}{d\phi}\right)^4 & \text{if}\ 0\le \phi < d\phi \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

(for the double-sided form, add two further terms under the substitution $\phi := 1 - \phi$.) In Java:

```
public static double blep(double t, final double dt) {
    double y = 0;
    if (0 <= t && t < 2 * dt) {
        final double x = t / dt;
        double u = 2 - x;
        u *= u;
        u *= u;
        y += u;
        if (t < dt) {
            double v = 1 - x;
            v *= v;
            v *= v;
            y -= 4 * v;
        }
    }
    return y / 12;
}
```

and this must be added on the *right* of the discontinuity and subtracted on its *left*. Hence, the sawtooth is:

```
public static double saw(double t, double dt) {
    double v = 2 * t - 1;
    v += blep(t, dt);
    v -= blep(1 - t, dt);
    return v;
}
```

(note that this is a positive-going ramp. For a negative going one, built on $1-2\phi$, subtract and then add the BLEPs.) A square wave or pulse with variable duty cycle $2d\phi < d < 1 - 2d\phi$ can be built from a difference of phase shifted sawtooth waves, or directly by “polyBLEPping” on both discontinuities in the cycle:

```
public static double sqr(double t, double dt) {
    double v = Math.signum(2 * t - 1);
    v += blep(t, dt);
    v -= blep(1 - t, dt);
    v += blep(0.5 - t, dt);
    v -= blep(t - 0.5, dt);
    return v;
}
```

If your oscillator is a triangle wave, then you do need to use the poly*BLAMP* residual. This can be found by integrating the polyBLEP residual, and scaling appropriately to the slope of the ramp it will be applied to. In single-sided form:

$$
-\frac{d\phi}{15}\,\begin{cases}
\left(2-\frac{\phi}{d\phi}\right)^5 & \text{if}\ 0 \le \phi < 2\phi \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} +\
\frac{d\phi}{15}\,\begin{cases}
4\left(1-\frac{\phi}{d\phi}\right)^5 & \text{if}\ 0 \le \phi < d\phi \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

(for the double-sided form, add two further terms under the substitution $\phi := 1 - \phi$.) The polyBLAMP residual in Java:

```
public static double blamp(double t, double dt) {
    double y = 0;
    if (0 <= t && t < 2 * dt) {
        final double x = t / dt;
        double u = 2 - x, u2 = u * u;
        u *= u2 * u2;
        y -= u;
        if (t < dt) {
            double v = 1 - x, v2 = v * v;
            v *= v2 * v2;
            y += 4 * v;
        }
    }
    return y * dt / 15;
}
```

Then the triangle oscillator is:

```
public static double tri(double t, double dt) {
    double v = 2 * Math.abs(2 * t - 1) - 1;
    v += blamp(t, dt);
    v += blamp(1 - t, dt);
    t += 0.5;
    t -= Math.floor(t);
    v -= blamp(t, dt);
    v -= blamp(1 - t, dt);
    return v;
}
```